# How to evaluate jQuery on the server in c#

Tags: c#, jquery

Following [Rick Strahl's example](https://west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/10688.aspx) we evaluate javascript on the server.

Now I want to leverage jQuery. However, evaluating the jQuery script gives an error: 'Expected identifier or string' Any clue what this might be?

Ultimately I want to render [jQuery Templates](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/05/07/jquery-templates-and-data-linking-and-microsoft-contributing-to-jquery.aspx) on the server in the same way as they are rendered in the browser.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why would you want to do this? If it's just for rendering the the template without postbacks, you might just as well insert your json into the view and have it render the template on the client side

Comment: Hi Adrian, our clients can define templates which are used in the browser. Now we want to use the same syntax to define templates for PDF. We convert rendered html to PDF on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few way of evaluating Javascript on the server. Just a quick google on 'Microsoft JScript' or 'VsaEngine' will help you.

However, evaluating jQuery is not possible. A good explanation can be found here: http://jint.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=80197

I am still interested in finding a solution.